# Converting db2 column names in select to be lowercase in json file

Tags: sql, db2

I currently have a very simple select that my code then dumps into JSON

```
SELECT user, phone
FROM table t;
```

But the select returns all uppercase column names, resulting in uppercase JSON keys, which I don't want. Is there a way in DB2 to return lowercase column names?

Comment: Hint:  `LOWER()`.

Comment: I tried that but it just returns 0001 and 0002 as the column naems

Comment: Hint 2.0: ignore above hint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get lowercase **columns names** (not data) in DB2, you must use double quotes around the column names.

```
SELECT user as "user", phone as "phone"
FROM table t;
```

Comment: But actually it may depend on your tool you use. For example, if you use some jdbc-based tool, it may use either ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName or ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel, the result may depends on some property set. [Examples of ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName and ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel values](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_c0052593.html)

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Hey, since you seem to have a lot of knowledge with DB2, do you know how to retain the ID (primary key) of an inserted or updated record? I just asked a question about this and I've yet to find anything on the topic

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result of the query to be small, try this

```
SELECT LOWER(user), LOWER(phone)
FROM table t;
```

Comment: For more details about DB2's lower() function see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_lower.html.

Answer (score -3):

Use the LOWER() function;

```
    SELECT LOWER(user) AS 'user', LOWER(phone) AS 'phone'
    FROM table t;
```

Comment: I have tried this but it just returns the column names as 00001 and 00002

Comment: It now says 'token [ was invalid'

Comment: replace the [ with apostrophes;   SELECT LOWER(user) AS 'user', LOWER(phone) AS 'phone' FROM table t;

Comment: "user" is a keyword so you can't say: LOWER(user) AS user. you could try LOWER(user) AS username or something like that if apostrophes don't work

Comment: That's so strange, it didn't work either. I can use double quotes but then the actual column name has double quotes on it

Comment: Quoted identifiers use double quotes; single quotes are for character literals.